# Solve the integral $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^\frac{1}{10}}{1+e^x}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

While solving a certain problem, I got stuck at this integral $$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^\frac{1}{10}}{1+e^x}dx$$ I tried elementary methods but nothing works. The last option would be a series solution. Can we solve this in closed form?

Comment: If you gave some context as to where this came from, we'd maybe have a bit better of a shot at giving an answer.

Comment: Wolframalpha says no, to a closed form, which is not surprising.

Comment: Yes, Cornman. Already checked that. I wonder if it can be expressed in terms of some non-elementary functions if it resists to be in the closed form. You see it looks so cute and simple..but a monster!

Comment: why don't you use numerical methods if you just need to evaluate it?

Comment: @Vasya Actually, I need to solve something general containing two parameters $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{i+\frac{1}{10}}}{1+e^{nx}}dx$ where $i=0,1,2...$ and $n=1,2,3...$. I need to use it in analytic form somewhere not the numerical value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that a closed form exists but things could be done.

Considering
$$I=\int \frac{x^a}{1+e^{nx}}\,dx$$ by Taylor
$$\frac{1}{1+e^{nx}}=\frac 12+\sum_{p=0}^\infty  n^{2 p+1}\frac{E_{2 p+1}(0)}{2 (2 p+1)!}x^{2p+1}$$ where appear Euler polynomials.

This makes 
$$J=\int_0^1 \frac{x^a}{1+e^{nx}}\,dx=\frac{1}{2 (a+1)}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{E_{2 p+1}(0)\, n^{2 p+1}}{(2 p+1)! (a+2 p+2)}$$

At least for your case $a=\frac 1 {10}$ and $n=1$, this seems to converge very fast (considering $\sum_{p=0}^q$)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 q & \text{result} \\
 0 & 0.33549783549783549784 \\
 1 & 0.34057913631084362792 \\
 2 & 0.34023760625619881917 \\
 3 & 0.34026363261324369474 \\
 4 & 0.34026151806647155721 \\
 5 & 0.34026169689918740783 \\
 6 & 0.34026168134981889845 \\
 7 & 0.34026168272958721037 \\
 8 & 0.34026168260523494156 \\
 9 & 0.34026168261658077711 \\
 10 & 0.34026168261553523742 \\
\cdots & \\
\infty &0.34026168261562407432
\end{array}
\right)$$